# python pandas Conditional Apply function with .shift

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Suppose I have this dataframe and I and I am asked to calculate weighted average.
I looked at this solution: [How to calculate vwap (volume weighted average price) using groupby and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854512/how-to-calculate-vwap-volume-weighted-average-price-using-groupby-and-apply)

But this does not exactly answer my question.

```
    ticker  date       quantity     price        holdings
    VLO     2014-02-19  5500.0      50.852800    5500
    VLO     2016-03-29  -1350.0     65.138200    4150
    VLO     2017-04-21   900.0      64.91643     5050
    VLO     2017-11-27  -985.0      81.886800    4065
```

1. Quantity can be positive, which means it is a buy, If negative, 
   it is sell.
2. wapp = previous wapp if quantity is negative.
3. Otherwise, wapp = (quantity*price) + (previous_holdings *previous_wapp)/ current_holdings

So, this is the correct wapp for the above dataframe:

```
    ticker  date       quantity     price        holdings   wapp
    VLO     2014-02-19  5500.0      50.852800    5500       50.8528
    VLO     2016-03-29  -1350.0     65.138200    4150       50.8528
    VLO     2017-04-21   900.0      64.91643     5050       53.35919
    VLO     2017-11-27  -985.0      81.886800    4065       53.35919
```

So, when there is a sell: no wapp change but holdings do change. 
Subsequently, the next wapp gets affected.

Is there a way to do so in pandas, or should I resort
to python?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can do "recursive" transformations like this with pure numpy/pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a "for" loop necessary if elements of the a numpy vector are dependent upon the previous element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-a-for-loop-necessary-if-elements-of-the-a-numpy-vector-are-dependent-upon-t)

Comment: you can look at something like numba or cython to speed up the loop

Comment: Thanks maxymoo. I guess will have to iterate over it to get the result I want. That is what I thought originally, but wanted to clarify.