# How to calculate Volume Weighted Average Price (VWAP) using a pandas dataframe with ask and bid price?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, quantitative-finance

How do i create another column called vwap which calculates the vwap if my table is as shown below?

```
             time            bid_size   bid       ask  ask_size trade trade_size phase  
0   2019-01-07 07:45:01.064515  495   152.52    152.54    19     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
1   2019-01-07 07:45:01.110072  31    152.53    152.54    19     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
2   2019-01-07 07:45:01.116596  32    152.53    152.54    19     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
3   2019-01-07 07:45:01.116860  32    152.53    152.54    21     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
4   2019-01-07 07:45:01.116905  34    152.53    152.54    21     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
5   2019-01-07 07:45:01.116982  34    152.53    152.54    31     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
6   2019-01-07 07:45:01.147901  38    152.53    152.54    31     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
7   2019-01-07 07:45:01.189971  38    152.53    152.54    31     ask     15.0    OPEN   
8   2019-01-07 07:45:01.189971  38    152.53    152.54    16     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
9   2019-01-07 07:45:01.190766  37    152.53    152.54    16     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
10  2019-01-07 07:45:01.190856  37    152.53    152.54    15     NaN      NaN    OPEN
11  2019-01-07 07:45:01.190856  37    152.53    152.54    16     ask      1.0    OPEN   
12  2019-01-07 07:45:01.193938  37    152.53    152.55   108     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
13  2019-01-07 07:45:01.193938  37    152.53    152.54    15     ask     15.0    OPEN   
14  2019-01-07 07:45:01.194326  2     152.54    152.55   108     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
15  2019-01-07 07:45:01.194453  2     152.54    152.55    97     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
16  2019-01-07 07:45:01.194479  6     152.54    152.55    97     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
17  2019-01-07 07:45:01.194507  19    152.54    152.55    97     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
18  2019-01-07 07:45:01.194532  19    152.54    152.55    77     NaN      NaN    OPEN   
19  2019-01-07 07:45:01.194598  19    152.54    152.55    79     NaN      NaN    OPEN
```

Sorry, the table is not clear, but  the second most right column is trade_size, on its left is trade, which shows the side of the trade( bid or ask). if both trade_size and trade are NaN, it indicates that no trade occur at that timestamp.

If df['trade'] == "ask", trade price will be the price in column 'ask' and if df['trade] == "bid", the trade price will be the price in column 'bid'. Since there are 2 prices, may I ask how can i calculate the vwap, df['vwap']?

My idea is to use np.cumsum().

Comment: What is the equation for VMAP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854512/how-to-calculate-vwap-volume-weighted-average-price-using-groupby-and-apply

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/vwap.asp

Comment: Which price should you use - bid or ask?

Comment: if df['trade'] == "ask", use df['ask]. Else If df['trade] == "bid", use df["bid"]. If df['trade'] == NaN, it means no trade

Comment: Thank you. What is your expected output?

Comment: For one line only the VWAP will be the trade price. If you want VWAP for a period, then, first, you must decide the time time period you want.

Comment: @edesz The expeced output will be another column called 'vwap'.

Comment: @edinho the time period will just be the start and end of the dataframe is that possible?

Comment: of course the actual df is much longer

Comment: @atjw94, do you have calculated numbers that you are expecting for VMAP?

Comment: @edesz sorry nope..

Comment: in fact I am not too sure how to

Comment: Thank you so much to the both of you @edesz and @edinho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to give you the price from the correct column (`bid` or `ask`) depending on the value in the `trade` column.  Note that this gives you the bid price when no trade occurs, but because this is then multiplied by a `NaN` trade size it won't matter. I also forward filled the VWAP.

```
volume = df['trade_size']
price = np.where(df['trade'].eq('ask'), df['ask'], df['bid'])  
df = df.assign(VWAP=((volume * price).cumsum() / vol.cumsum()).ffill())

>>> df
        time    bid_size    bid ask ask_size    trade   trade_size  phase   VWAP
0   2019-01-07  07:45:01.064515 495 152.52  152.54  19  NaN NaN OPEN    NaN
1   2019-01-07  07:45:01.110072 31  152.53  152.54  19  NaN NaN OPEN    NaN
2   2019-01-07  07:45:01.116596 32  152.53  152.54  19  NaN NaN OPEN    NaN
3   2019-01-07  07:45:01.116860 32  152.53  152.54  21  NaN NaN OPEN    NaN
4   2019-01-07  07:45:01.116905 34  152.53  152.54  21  NaN NaN OPEN    NaN
5   2019-01-07  07:45:01.116982 34  152.53  152.54  31  NaN NaN OPEN    NaN
6   2019-01-07  07:45:01.147901 38  152.53  152.54  31  NaN NaN OPEN    NaN
7   2019-01-07  07:45:01.189971 38  152.53  152.54  31  ask 15.0    OPEN    152.54
8   2019-01-07  07:45:01.189971 38  152.53  152.54  16  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
9   2019-01-07  07:45:01.190766 37  152.53  152.54  16  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
10  2019-01-07  07:45:01.190856 37  152.53  152.54  15  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
11  2019-01-07  07:45:01.190856 37  152.53  152.54  16  ask 1.0 OPEN    152.54
12  2019-01-07  07:45:01.193938 37  152.53  152.55  108 NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
13  2019-01-07  07:45:01.193938 37  152.53  152.54  15  ask 15.0    OPEN    152.54
14  2019-01-07  07:45:01.194326 2   152.54  152.55  108 NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
15  2019-01-07  07:45:01.194453 2   152.54  152.55  97  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
16  2019-01-07  07:45:01.194479 6   152.54  152.55  97  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
17  2019-01-07  07:45:01.194507 19  152.54  152.55  97  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
18  2019-01-07  07:45:01.194532 19  152.54  152.55  77  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
19  2019-01-07  07:45:01.194598 19  152.54  152.55  79  NaN NaN OPEN    152.54
```

Comment: What is vol in "vol.cumsum()" ?

Comment: Should be ‘volume’

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach

Append `VMAP` column full of `NaN`s

```
df['VMAP'] = np.nan
```

Calculate `VMAP` (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44854723/4057186) equation [provided by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699494/how-to-calculate-volume-weighted-average-price-vwap-using-a-pandas-dataframe-w#comment98081324_55699494)) and assign values based on `ask` or `bid`, [as requierd by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699494/how-to-calculate-volume-weighted-average-price-vwap-using-a-pandas-dataframe-w?noredirect=1#comment98081369_55699494)

```
for trade in ['ask','bid']:
    # Find indexes of `ask` or `buy`
    bid_idx = df[df.trade==trade].index

    # Slice DF based on `ask` or `buy`, using indexes
    df.loc[bid_idx, 'VMAP'] = (
        (df.loc[bid_idx, 'trade_size'] * df.loc[bid_idx, trade]).cumsum()
        /
        (df.loc[bid_idx, 'trade_size']).cumsum()
                )

print(df.iloc[:,1:])
               time  bid_size     bid     ask  ask_size trade  trade_size phase    VMAP
0   07:45:01.064515       495  152.52  152.54        19   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
1   07:45:01.110072        31  152.53  152.54        19   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
2   07:45:01.116596        32  152.53  152.54        19   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
3   07:45:01.116860        32  152.53  152.54        21   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
4   07:45:01.116905        34  152.53  152.54        21   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
5   07:45:01.116982        34  152.53  152.54        31   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
6   07:45:01.147901        38  152.53  152.54        31   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
7   07:45:01.189971        38  152.53  152.54        31   ask        15.0  OPEN  152.54
8   07:45:01.189971        38  152.53  152.54        16   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
9   07:45:01.190766        37  152.53  152.54        16   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
10  07:45:01.190856        37  152.53  152.54        15   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
11  07:45:01.190856        37  152.53  152.54        16   ask         1.0  OPEN  152.54
12  07:45:01.193938        37  152.53  152.55       108   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
13  07:45:01.193938        37  152.53  152.54        15   ask        15.0  OPEN  152.54
14  07:45:01.194326         2  152.54  152.55       108   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
15  07:45:01.194453         2  152.54  152.55        97   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
16  07:45:01.194479         6  152.54  152.55        97   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
17  07:45:01.194507        19  152.54  152.55        97   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
18  07:45:01.194532        19  152.54  152.55        77   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
19  07:45:01.194598        19  152.54  152.55        79   NaN         NaN  OPEN     NaN
```

**EDIT**

As `@edinho` [correctly indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699494/how-to-calculate-volume-weighted-average-price-vwap-using-a-pandas-dataframe-w#comment98081599_55699494), the `VMAP` is the same as the `trade_price` column.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here it is

```
df['trade_price'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['bid'] if x['trade']=='bid' else x['ask'], axis=1)
df['vwap'] = (df['trade_price'] * df['trade_size']).cumsum() / df['trade_size'].fillna(0).cumsum()
```

The first line:
It saves the trade_price in a new column, so it is easier to retrieve it later.
If you want, you can delete this line and make a function (maybe it is easier to read). But I prefer to see the intermediary results.
Q: why it has values even when there is no trade?
A: because of the way the lambda is written. The `else` captures the `ask` price. But it won't make a difference, because of the next step.

Second line:
Here the real calculation takes places.
The first part calculate the total volume traded until that moment (as you said, using cumulative sums makes life easier).
The second part calculates the total volume traded until that moment (again, cumulative sums).
If you want, you can break this line and make more intermediary columns.
Q: why the `fillna(0)`?
A: so the total volume don't get `NaNs` and you don't get a division error
Q: why so many `NaNs` in the `vwap` column?
A: Because of the lines that don't have trade. You can fill them with `0s`, but would be better to keep the 'no trade' information.

Ps.: you may get a wrong result as it is considering volume and price only in the same direction. But, you could try to invert some signal to fix the volume in the way you expect (for instance: changing the `ask` price to negative).

and this code output:

```
    trade_price vwap
1   152.54  NaN
2   152.54  NaN
3   152.54  NaN
4   152.54  NaN
5   152.54  NaN
6   152.54  NaN
7   152.54  NaN
8   152.54  152.54
9   152.54  NaN
10  152.54  NaN
11  152.54  NaN
12  152.54  152.54
13  152.55  NaN
14  152.54  152.54
15  152.55  NaN
16  152.55  NaN
17  152.55  NaN
18  152.55  NaN
19  152.55  NaN
20  152.55  NaN
```